# How get a datetime string to suffix my filenames?

Tags: python, date, formatting, string-formatting

I need a function to generate datafile names with a suffix which must be the current date and time.

I want for the date Feb, 18 2014 15:02 something like this:

```
data_201402181502.txt
```

But this is that I get: `data_2014218152.txt`

My code...

```
import time

prefix_file = 'data'
tempus = time.localtime(time.time())    
suffix = str(tempus.tm_year)+str(tempus.tm_mon)+str(tempus.tm_mday)+
    str(tempus.tm_hour)+str(tempus.tm_min)
name_file = prefix_file + '_' + suffix + '.txt'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`time.strftime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime) for this, which handles padding leading zeros e.g. on the month:

```
from time import strftime

name_file = "{0}_{1}.txt".format(prefix_file, 
                                 strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M"))
```

If you simply turn an integer to a string using `str`, it will not have the leading zero: `str(2) == '2'`. You can, however, specify this using the `str.format` syntax: `"{0:02d}".format(2) == '02'`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want

```
 date.strftime(format)
```

The format string will allow you to control the output of strftime, try something like:
"%b-%d-%y"
From http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

Answer (score 1):

Using [`str.format`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) with [`datetime.datetime`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) object:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> '{}_{:%Y%m%d%H%M}.txt'.format('filename', datetime.datetime.now())
'filename_201402182313.txt'
```